# What is the difference between a 9 dots menu icon and a 7 dots?

Tags: navigation, buttons, icons, menu

What does it possibly mean? Can it be used as 'go back to menu'?

https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/[image: 7 dots menu]data/icons/social-media-vol-3/24/_dots-512.png

Comment: Do you have a specific UX question where those icons show different test results? Otherwise the question is not really suited for this site.

Comment: This question is not exactly off-topic in my opinion, is just low-quality. In fact, this could be flagged as duplicate and I think the answer can be found here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82391/should-we-use-the-3x3-9-dots-icon-as-an-apps-menu. If you ask what is the difference, then this is obvious. If you ask what icon should you use and why, please check the link I posted in this comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we use the 3x3 9-dots icon as an apps menu?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82391/should-we-use-the-3x3-9-dots-icon-as-an-apps-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what this is supposed to represent, a user will never intuitively know what it is supposed to be.

It's a representation of somebody losing their Gestalt marbles. (2 to be exact)