# Is it right to place a icon and text together?

Tags: design, dashboard, administration

I'm working on an admin dashboard design, for some shipping transports. I've designed couple of dashboard before. Everytime i was asked this question.

Normally in dashboard design we will place icon as well as text together right?
Is it right to have both the things together? if yes or no, why?

Comment: See [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/when-to-use-icons-vs-icons-with-text-vs-just-text-links/1803#1803).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never good to use icons without labels because users with different backgrounds and contexts will understand them differently. Icon A may mean A to me but B to you.

Always use labels to be safe. Icons provide a visual focus point for the eye, while the label describes exactly what the icons stands for or where it will the take the user to.

For more on this, read this:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/